# Limiting amount of requests from a client to the WCF

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

Is there any way to limit the amount of requests that a client can do to a WCF at a time?

if so, I could limit the amount of requests dynamically according to my client settings?

for example, a cliente can make up to 10 simultaneous requests for my WCF service.

Comment: Define simultaneous

Comment: Yes, there is a behavior called `maxConcurrentCalls` that you can set accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to limit the amount of requests that a client can do
>   to a WCF at a time?

Yes, there is a behavior called `maxConcurrentCalls`. As per documentation it's

*A positive integer that limits the number of messages that currently process across a ServiceHost. Calls in excess of the limit are queued. Setting this value to 0 is equivalent to setting it to Int32.MaxValue. The default is 16.*

For more, Read [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stcheng/2009/01/06/wcfthings-that-will-impact-concurrency-capacity-behavior-of-wcf-service-with-simoultaneous-client-requestsconnections/)